# Suppose there is a single sub-space W such that $U \oplus W=V$, prove that $U=V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Need help solving the following question:

> Let $U$ be a sub-space of a finite dimension vector space $V$, such that
>    $U\neq\{0\}$. Suppose there is a **single** sub-space W such that $U
>  \oplus W=V$, prove that $U=V$.

What I've try to do:
Let $v\in V, v\neq0\ $. let's say $v\notin U$, and show that there is another sub-space $W'\neq W$ that sets $V=U \oplus W'$, but couldn't find this sub-space.

Comment: **final** dimension vector space or **finite**?

Comment: the dimension of $W$ must be $\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $U \subsetneq V$. Then, we have to show that if $W$ satisfies $U \oplus W = V$, then $W$ is not unique.

We know one example of $W$ : This is given by the orthogonal complement of $U$ in $V$ under the inner product given by the standard basis, $U^\perp$. That is, we have $U \oplus U^\perp = V$.

Pick any vector $0 \neq u \in U$, and let $W$  be obtained as follows : take a basis $b_i$ of $U^\perp$, and let $W$ be the span of $b_i + u$. I leave you to check that $U \oplus W  = V$.

This shows that the complement of $U$ in $V$ is never unique, when $U$ is a non-trivial subspace of $V$.